# Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, macos, apache, postgresql, osx-elcapitan

I am running the latest version of PHP (currently 5.6.22) on OSX El Capitan and Apache server.

I am trying to use PostgreSQL database and actually, yesterday already worked but after I haver overridden httpd.conf file with a default one (I guess this is the problem) I got this message:

> Call to undefined function pg_connect() in ...

The thing is that I haven't changed php.ini file. If I run phpinfo(); I get etc/php.ini for a Configuration File. So I am positive that Apache choose the right php.ini file and that correct extensions are loaded:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

What can cause this error ? Also I have installed pgAdmin 3 and I can successfully run SQL queries on created database (which I have used yesterday for this site I am working on).

EDIT:

This is what I get in error_log file when I restart Apache server and try to run that specific page (which calls pg_connect):

> [Thu Jun 02 15:28:15.595496 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 476]
>   AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down [Thu Jun 02 15:28:16.515774
>   2016] [so:warn] [pid 670] AH01574: module php5_module is already
>   loaded, skipping PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_curl.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_curl.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mbstring.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mysqli.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_mysqli.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll'
>   - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_pgsql.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_sqlite.dll'
>   - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pdo_sqlite.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_soap.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_soap.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sockets.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sockets.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sqlite3.dll' -
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_sqlite3.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 [Thu Jun 02 15:28:16.615703
>   2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 670] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
>   PHP/5.5.31 configured -- resuming normal operations [Thu Jun 02
>   15:28:16.615786 2016] [core:notice] [pid 670] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' [Thu Jun 02 15:28:20.869683 2016]
>   [:error] [pid 674] [client 127.0.0.1:49594] PHP Fatal error:  Call to
>   undefined function pg_connect() in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/site/database.php on line 10

Comment: `php_pgsql.dll` is enabled?

Comment: @maximkou Yeah, I forgot to add that. In php.ini , extension=php_pgsql.dll was already uncommented.

Comment: Can you show your apache log?

Comment: @maximkou You mean content from access_log file ?

Comment: No, `error_log` file

Comment: @maximkou I just copy/pasted error log. It is not that readable, but I hope you'll figure out what are the errors.

Comment: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_pgsql.dll'

Comment: Looks like your extensions directory changed.

Comment: Set right `extension_dir` in `php.ini`. Maybe in old `httpd.conf` you set this?

Comment: @maximkou Just checking. In php.ini there is no extension_dir set. Also in httpd.conf I can't find anything related to this. Which setting in httpd.conf should I look for? Also should I explicitly set in php.ini extension_dir to "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113647/discussion-between-maximkou-and-whirlwind).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your pgsql extension is not installed or is not compatible with your current server build (x86/x64).

1. Check if you have the correct file in you ***ext*** folder: `php_pgsql.so` (or `php_pgsql.dll` if youre running on windows)
2. Search for the line `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in your `php.ini`. Then just add it if not found or remove the comma if its commented
3. Run `phpinfo()` and check if the extension is enabled

If you found it, its good to go

Comment: Actually, there is no php_pgsql.so in extension dir. If you have by some chance followed mine and @maximkou chat conversation, you then might now what I have tried so far... If you have some advices, I would be happy to hear...